# Swapped from university computer to home, why am i getting FreeImage.h no such file or directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've moved from my university computer to my home computer, installed VS and C++ on it, however when trying to run my code from a lecture i'm now getting:

Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error C1083  Cannot open include file: 'FreeImage.h': No such file or directory wingl2013_14 c:\users\brads\desktop\game\framework 2014\wingl2013_14\textureloader.h 1  

Error (active) Cannot open source file "FreeImage.h" wingl2013_14 c:\Users\Brads\Desktop\Game\framework 2014\wingl2013_14\TextureLoader.h 1
```

have i installed something wrong? Or not installed something, i've tried a web search but found nothing except dodgy looking sites. 
Thanks.

both versions of vs were 2015

Comment: add the correct folder to your include paths

Comment: Did you install the [freeimage library](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) on your computer at home?

Comment: i already have if this is what you mean:
    #include <FreeImage.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>

Answer (score 1):

> Or not installed something, i've tried a web search but found nothing except dodgy looking sites.

Yes, you have missed to install the [FreeImage library](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) that is not part of Visual Studio.

It's easy to find if you just google `FreeImage.h`

Comment: Thanks a lot, where would i save this ?

Comment: @evilsponge Hmm, download and follow their installation instructions. May be you need to adapt some build files to your local environment.